# Getting an integer from an array of hexadecimal characters?

Tags: c

I came across this code in a popular answer on another stackexchange site, but I only understand a portion of the syntax and purpose behind it:

```
static const unsigned char code[] = "\xb0\x2a\xc3";
int value;
value = (*(uint8_t(*)())code)();
```

From what I can gather, the array of hexadecimal characters (syntactically represented as a char pointer) is cast to an unsigned integer. But what I don't understand is:

1. The parentheses
   **a.** especially those at the end, prior to the terminating semicolon, which make it seem as if the `code` array is called as a function
   **b.** the pair immediately following `uint8_t` containing the asterisk
2. The asterisks
   **a.** what's being dereferenced, and in what order?
   **b.** Why is an asterisk being passed to `uint8_t`?
3. How is it that the entire array can be cast to a different type, rather than having to do so for each element? Would this work if `unsigned char` and `uint8_t` were of different sizes?

Comment: This casts the pointer to the char array to a function pointer, which is then called ,i.e. the program counter is set to the address of the array, executing the bytes there if it is valid machine code. Note that this might fail on some platforms/architectures, since the segment where the char array resides might not be executable resulting in a SIGSEGV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the array of hexadecimal characters (syntactically represented as a char pointer)

No. "Hexadecimal character" is not a thing. Also, there is no char pointer there.

`code` is an array of unsigned chars (i.e. bytes). This array has 4 elements: `0xb0`, `0x2a`, `0xc3`, `0x00` (or equivalently: `176`, `42`, `195`, `0`).

The type `uint8_t (*)()` is not an unsigned integer, it's a pointer to a function (of no arguments) returning a `uint8_t`.

What's going on in `(*(uint8_t(*)())code)()`:

- We have `code` (an array) in an expression. It is not the operand of `sizeof` or `&`, so it decays to a pointer to its first element.
- This pointer (of type `unsigned char *`) to `code[0]` is cast to a different type: `uint8_t (*)()`, i.e. a pointer to a function returning a `uint8_t`.

  The general form of a cast is `( TYPE ) EXPR`. Here we have a `TYPE` of `int8_t (*)()` and our `EXPR` is `code`.
- This function pointer is dereferenced (with `*`), yielding a function. This operation is redundant because any function value immediately decays back to a pointer (unless it is the operand of `&`, in which case you get back a function pointer anyway).
- The function pointer is indeed called by the final pair of parens, `()`.

What this code actually does is highly platform dependent. On some platforms casting a data pointer to a function pointer gives you a "function" whose code is specified by the data, i.e. this ends up jumping to and executing the contents of `code` as machine code.